# jQuery autocomplete expands to take up entire screen

Tags: jquery, user-interface, textbox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete box into a search bar. When I being to type in the text, the box expands to fill my entire screen. Is there any way I can decrease the size of the box that pops up? I'm sort of new to jQuery, so I'm hoping it is just some option I can set. Code is like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var data = {% autoescape false %}{{job_names}}{% endautoescape %};
    $("#job_names").autocomplete({source : data});
  });
</script>

<form name= "search_form" method= "post" action= "/" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
  <input id="job_names" type= "text"/>
  <input type= "submit" value= "Search" id= "search"/>
</form>
```

A thing to note, job_names is a list passed in through my flask/python backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your html page, it will apply an overflow setting and set the width of the auto complete list:

```
/**causes the autocomplete to align left and overflow with vertical scroll bar **/
    ul
    {
        text-align:left;
        width: 150px;           
    }
    .ui-autocomplete  
    {
        max-height: 200px;
        overflow-y: auto; 
        overflow-x: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/4J9tK/

Comment: Thanks, this made a huge improvement and is going to lead me in the right direction I think.